# Opencart currency conversion

Tags: php, opencart, currency

I have an installation of Opencart which includes multiple currency checking options. If someone changes the currency all product amounts are converted to the selected currency. I want to know where the conversion function is written within Opencart so that if a markup price needs to be added, it can be done here within the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `system > library > currency` as this is where all the functions are stored and read from regarding the currency. There is also a function called `convert` which deals with the basic conversion.